# Uniqueness of LDL decomposition of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a real and positive semi-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with rank $p < n$.

It is known from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) that $A$ admits a decomposition as
$$
A = L D L^\top,       \quad \quad\quad                      (1)
$$
where $L$ is lower unit triangular; $D$ is diagonal and the number of its non-zero diagonal entries equals the rank of $A$.

The question is that given $A$, if the $D$ matrix in the above decomposition is unique.

I think the decomposition, and thus the pair $(L,D)$, is not unique, because the columns of $L$ that correspond to the zero diagonal entires in $D$ can be modified freely without violating $(1)$. However, my interest here is the uniqueniess of $D$ only.

Comment: "lower unit triangular" is a lower triangular matrix with its main diagonal entries being ones.

Answer (score 1):

you rarely have uniqueness in factorizations involving singular matrices, and your argument about $L$ not being unique is correct.  It is true, however, that $D$ is unique.

suppose
$A=L_1D_1L_1^* = L_2D_2L_2^*$

where $D_1$, $D_2$ are diagonal matrices and $L_1$, $L_2$ are lower triangular with 1's on the diagonal.
$D_2 = L_2^{-1}L_1D_1L_1^*(L_2^*)^{-1}=  \big(L_2^{-1}L_1\big)D_1\big(L_2^{-1}L_1\big)^{*} = R^*D_1R$
with $R:=\big(L_2^{-1}L_1\big)^{*}$ which is upper triangular with ones on the diagonal

$\implies D_2R^{-1}=R^*D_1$
the LHS is uppper triangular while the RHS is lower triangular, which in fact implies each side is diagonal.  And since $R$ has ones on the diagonal:
$\implies D_2= D_2R^{-1}=R^*D_1 =D_1$

alternatively, looking at $D_2R^{-1}=R^*D_1$ and examining component (k,k) of each side
$\implies d^{(2)}_{k,k} \cdot 1 =d^{(1)}_{k,k}\cdot 1 \implies  D_2 = D_1$